# How to "expand" multi-value fields in JSON using SQL in Java (possibly with LATERAL VIEW)?

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to transform my JSON input from

```
col1 | col2
row1   [value1, value2]
row2   [value3, value2]
```

to

```
col1 | col2
row1   value1
row1   value2
row2   value3
row2   value2
```

Apparently `LATERAL VIEW` is the way to go, but I can't seem to get it right.

I've been trying the following:

```
df= sqlContext.sql(
        "SELECT col1, col2" +
        "FROM temptable LATERAL VIEW col2 AS col2"
);
```

(Note: the variable `sqlContext` is actually a `HiveContext`.)

But this gives me `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: missing EOF at 'LATERAL' near 'temptable ';`. What does it mean by End of File?

How can I achieve this in JAVA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a space between col2 and FROM in your query. The way you wrote it, the query is then `SELECT col1, col2FROM temptable LATERAL VIEW col2 AS col2`
but you should write

```
df= sqlContext.sql(
    "SELECT col1, col2 FROM temptable LATERAL VIEW col2 AS col2"
);
```

Comment: This isn't Java syntax, this is a domain-specific language provided by the DataFrame API. What you are looking for is the function [`explode`]. But I don't know the syntax with Java, I'm using scala

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm just not familiar with the nomenclature :D Point is I was looking for the kind of syntax I made up in the question. [`explode`] is Scala-specific as far as I know, maybe there isn't a JAVA equivalent :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the following:

```
scala> val ds = Seq(("row1", Seq("value1", "value2")), ("row2", Seq("value3", "value2"))).toDF("col1", "col2")
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: array<string>]

scala> ds.show
+----+----------------+
|col1|            col2|
+----+----------------+
|row1|[value1, value2]|
|row2|[value3, value2]|
+----+----------------+
```

I'd use `explode` function as follows (and that's why there's no need for `LATERAL VIEW` in this use case):

```
scala> ds.select($"col1", explode($"col2") as "expl").show
+----+------+
|col1|  expl|
+----+------+
|row1|value1|
|row1|value2|
|row2|value3|
|row2|value2|
+----+------+
```

`LATERAL VIEW` is required when you'd like to `explode` two or more columns as Spark otherwise would give you the following exception:

```
scala> xys.select(explode($"xs"), explode($"ys")).show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Only one generator allowed per select clause but found 2: explode(xs), explode(ys);
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractGenerator$$anonfun$apply$20.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1670)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractGenerator$$anonfun$apply$20.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1662)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:62)
```